# 16v 26,400 mAh battery pack or 12v 35,200 mAh battery pack

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

I am creating a Li-ion battery pack that will allow me to charge my LiPo batteries when I am out in the field flying.

I currently have 48 18650 Li-ion batteries that I am using for my pack and I have a holder that is 8 by 6.  The charger that I use to charge my LiPo batteries accepts a voltage of 9-32V DC.  When charging a 12v 3S LiPo the charger draws around 1.4A, and each battery holds a capacity of 1300mAh.

What configuration should I go with in order to charge the maximum number of batteries, 16 Li-ion batteries per cell to get a total of 26,400mAh @ 16v or 12 Li-ion batteries per cell to get a total of 35,200mAh @ 12v?

Comment: Feed 16V to your charger to see the amount of current.

Comment: Charger specs missing, unclear what "1.3 mha" is, no schematic and boarderline off topic as in use of electronic devices.

Comment: It's the same energy either way. So it's down to what the charger prefers, and you're the one with its manual, not us.

Comment: @winny that was supposed to be mAh

Comment: It should be a very fiery explosion to watch that 1.3 mAh battery being charged with ~1 A, save for vague specs, or about 700 C. Anyhow, enought guesswork. VTC.

Comment: @winny what are you talking about

Comment: How much current does your charger consume when you feed it with 16V? It is important to compare it with 12V source.

Comment: @chupacabras it draws around 1.4-1.47A @ 12v
  and draws around 1.1 @ 16v and 0.04 at standby

Comment: @Austinthemighty You should add this important information to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your charger draws around 1.4-1.47A @ 12V and around 1.1A @ 16V.
I assume you are measuring it with the same charger's output current. In both cases charger takes 17.6W, so from this respect it doesn't matter what voltage you are feeding. You will have the same battery run-time.

Now it depends what other purposes are you going to use that battery for. 12V is more widespread than 16V. So it is more versatile to have 12V power source.

Comment: ok thank you, the only other thing that I am going to use it for is a soldering iron but that can run off of 9-24v